# PHP - Do not allow sessions across subdomains

Tags: php, session, subdomain

Ok, so I'm having an issue with a project I'm working on. I have a site with multiple subdomains. However, I've setup each subdomain to be it's own hosting account (meaning it has it's own hosting user and such). Now, I DON'T want cookies to be shared across the domains. One domain is a signup domain (http://signup.mydomain.com), one is a login domain (http://login.mydomain.com). However, after they signup(on the signup subdomain) I want to force them to log in on the "log in subdomain".

In firefox everything works fine. But for some reason in Internet explorer it's not creating a new session when they go from one subdomain to the other. It's still trying to read the old session file...but this isn't going to work because the session file is owned by the signup user...not the login user. Hence I am getting an error: open(/tmp/sess_91757a42a3b0ff0415e07ac62e603790, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13), which of course makes sense because of the file ownership issue.

Now, what I can't figure out is how to force internet explorer to start a new session between the two subdomains, and treat them like they are seperate sites (like they technically are).

Here is code I've tried with no success:

on the signup subdomain:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'signup.mydomain.com'); 
session_start();
```

on the login subdomain:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'login.mydomain.com'); 
session_start();
```

Then I also tried:

```
session_destroy();
$old_sessionid = session_id();
session_regenerate_id();
session_start();
```

Lastly, I tried different variations of above, with this as well (before the session_start():

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'signup.mydomain.com' );
```

Comment: Add subdomain to the server-side session attributes and invalidate the session when they switch subdomains?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the `$_COOKIE` array when IE requests the login subdomain? Might give you some insight into what's going on. You could also try giving unique names to each session with `session_name`. Also, what version of IE?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add the subomdain to the server-side session attribute and invalidated the session when they switch subdomains like suggested?  Any idea how I would go about this?  I'm running a LAMP server.  Also, this happens on all version of I.E. that I have tested from version 11 and older.  One additional odditiy, with I.E. 11, if I go from subdomain to subdomain I'm ok.  But if I go to the main site, then back to one of the subdomains this happens.  On older versions of I.E., no matter where I go (subdomain to subdomain or main domain to subdomain) I have the problem....

Comment: Also, as far as debugging the $_COOKIE array, I have gone in and looked in the session file in the /tmp folder itself.  I can see what is being set in the session, which is from whichever domain/subdomain   Then I.E. won't release the session so i can recreate a session on the next subdomain.   And since it won't release the session, it tries to read the session file from /tmp.  But the new subdomain doesn't own/have permissions to the file, so I get the "Permission denied" error.  I need to find a way for I.E. to let the old session go and start a brand new one when they switch subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i think I actually figured out what was going on.  I just happened to stumble upon it when looking over another issue with the site.  The root domain is using wordpress with the bulletproof security pro security module.  It turns out, by default they deny HEAD requests with this in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK|DEBUG) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

It's supposed to be in there to stop junk and spam bots, but apparently this was causing an issue with I.E. not releasing the session.  As soon as I removed the "HEAD" from it, the cookies started working the way they should.  Hopefully this helps someone else out in the future.

Comment: I've been battling this exact scenario for almost a year.  And this finally fixed the issue!